# Next.js always renders home page no matter what path

Tags: next.js

I have a new Next.js application, with an `index.tsx` and several other pages in my `pages` folder. However no matter what path I navigate to, it always renders the `index.tsx`. The URL in the address bar does change to the correct path, but the page content does not change. In-fact, any random path I enter will still always render the index page, even if the page doesn't exist.

What could possibly cause this?

Comment: when you say new Next.js what version? Should you be doing routing in app folder? Do you have layout.tsx?

Comment: @GotStu Version 13.5.6. I have an `_app.tsx`. I'm using Next.js's built-in routing. It's very basic there's nothing going on in this app yet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just in-case anyone else has this, it appears to be a bug in the latest version. I found an old working project that was on `"next": "^12.3.4"` and that fixed it.